# Faster matching code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that takes a list of Airline flightlegs and matches them up to give me full lines of flight.  The code works but.....  it takes a very long time (45-60 min for just 35,000 rows) due to the amount of data it has to go through.  This is compounded and the overall code takes about 2 hours to run.  Is there a faster method to get the same results?

Here is my current code that really bogs down the entire process:

```
Sub BuildingLines()
'strings together segments into trip

Dim i As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim T As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim f As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim g As Long


Dim y As String
Dim b As String

Set ref = Sheets("Ref")

With Sheets("MoveData")
z = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
x = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
Range(.Cells(1, 3), (.Cells(z, x + 3))).Clear
z = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
g = ref.Cells(24, 1).End(xlDown).Row

For a = 24 To g

    If ref.Cells(a, 2) = "" Then GoTo nexta

    f = ref.Cells(a, 2)
    c = ref.Cells(a, 3)
    l = ref.Cells(a, 4)
    Set LegTable = Range(.Cells(f, 1), .Cells(l, 1))

    For i = f To l

        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: Step 5 of 20 - Building lines for " & ref.Cells(a, 1) & " (" & (a - 23) & " A/C types of " & (g - 23) & ") : " & (i - f) + 1 & " Legs of " & c & " analyzed. (" & Format(((i - f) + 1) / c, "Percent") & ")"
    DoEvents

    'On Error GoTo NextI

    If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), LegTable, 0)) Then
        GoTo nexti

    Else
            y = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), LegTable, 0) + f - 1
            .Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Value2 = .Cells(y, 2)

                Do
                'On Error GoTo NextI
                If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(y, 2), LegTable, 0)) Then

                GoTo nexti
                Else
                    b = Application.Match(.Cells(y, 2), LegTable, 0) + f - 1
                    h = .Cells(b, 2)
                    .Cells(i, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1) = h
                    y = b
                End If
                Loop
nexti:

        End If

    b = ""
    y = ""

    Next i
nexta:
Next a
End With
End Sub
```

The data is all string data of about 50+ chars.

Thank you for any recomendations.

Comment: At first glance, you are doing each search **twice**, once to check for existence, and once to work with. You can get rid of that by putting the result of `Match` in a `Variant` variable and check with `If IsError(variable)`.

Comment: Another possible speedup is to sort your data ascending and use match with *binary search* (third parameter = `1` instead of `0`).

Comment: Also disable events and screen updating, and **dont** update the status bar at each inner iteration! maybe put it at the outer iteration. Minimize also the VBA-Excel exchange by loading the range of values into an array, etc..

Comment: I tried the binary search, but it doesn't work for this situation.  I already had the screen updating set to false but I do have the events on so that I can stop the code if need be.  I am working on only searching once to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: as for the status bar updating, it's the only way I know of to keep track of the progress.  Otherwise I am just staring at blank screen for a couple of hours.

Comment: I have never worked with arrays.  How would I go about replicating this using arrays?

Comment: To use binary search you need two things: 1- sort the data ascending and 2- after each match, check also if it is an *exact match* because it may be not the case.

Comment: Progress bar: You dont need to remove completely the progress bar, just to refresh it after each "batch" of loops. What I was saying is move it to the outher loop for example.

Comment: Arrays: 1- make `LegTable` a Variant and put the `.Value2` of the range inside. 2- Load also the range "B1:B" & f` into an array, for example.

Comment: so, I got the variable suggestion to work with the binary, but unfortunetly, the binary won't work right (although it was going faster until it stopped working).  I think I am down to using the array method.  I guess I will be researching how to do that tomorow.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Note that `MATCH` with binary search does not perform an "exact" match, but somehow the "closest". After it returns to you an index, check *again* if that cell exactly equals what you are searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much A.S.H.  with your help, I not only learned alot about using arrays, but also ended up cutting my runtime from about 90 minutes to just over 3 minutes.  This is my final working code that used a combination of your suggestions.

```
Sub BuildingLines()
'strings together segments into trip

Dim i As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim f As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim LegTable As Range
Dim TurnTable As Range
Dim FirstTurn() As Variant
Dim NextTurn() As Variant
Dim y As String
Dim b As String
Dim FTtext As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ref As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ref = wb.Sheets("Ref")

With Sheets("MoveData")
z = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
x = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
Range(.Cells(1, 3), (.Cells(z, x + 3))).Clear
z = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
g = ref.Cells(24, 1).End(xlDown).Row

For a = 24 To g

    If ref.Cells(a, 2) = "" Then GoTo NextA

    f = ref.Cells(a, 2)
    c = ref.Cells(a, 3)
    l = ref.Cells(a, 4)
    Set LegTable = Range(.Cells(f, 1), .Cells(l, 1))
    Set TurnTable = Range(.Cells(f, 1), .Cells(l, 2))

    FirstTurn = TurnTable


        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=LegTable, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
        .SetRange TurnTable
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    For i = f To l

        Application.StatusBar = "Progress: Step 5 of 20 - Building lines for " & ref.Cells(a, 1) & " (" & (a - 23) & " A/C types of " & (g - 23) & ") : " & (i - f) + 1 & " Legs of " & c & " analyzed. (" & Format(((i - f) + 1) / c, "Percent") & ")"
    DoEvents

    y = 0
    b = 0

        y = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), LegTable, 1)
        If .Cells(i, 2) <> FirstTurn(y, 1) Then GoTo NextI

        NextLeg = NextLeg + 1
        ReDim Preserve NextTurn(0, 1 To NextLeg)
        NextTurn(0, NextLeg) = FirstTurn(y, 2)

            Do
                FTtext = FirstTurn(y, 2)
                On Error GoTo errhdlr
                b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FTtext, LegTable, 1)
                If FTtext <> FirstTurn(b, 1) Then GoTo NextI

                NextLeg = NextLeg + 1
                ReDim Preserve NextTurn(0, 1 To NextLeg)
                NextTurn(0, NextLeg) = FirstTurn(b, 2)
                y = b
            Loop

errhdlr:
    Resume NextI
NextI:

    If NextLeg > 0 Then Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, NextLeg + 2)).Value = NextTurn
    Erase NextTurn
    NextLeg = 0
    Next i

Set LegTable = Nothing
Set TurnTable = Nothing
Erase NextTurn
Erase FirstTurn

NextA:
Next a
End With

End Sub
```

I first tried using just the arrays, but the Match function was WAY SLOWER in the arrays.  So I ended up using the Match to find the index and then grabbed the data from the array to build my second array which then became my output.  I can't wait to adapt my new found knowledge with the rest of this project and cut my runtime from 2+ hours to just minutes!! Thanks, again!!!